# Pre-bundle maps in Skobbler SDK 2.5.1

Tags: ios, skmaps

I started experimenting with the Skobbler SDK today, and downloaded the SDK and Demo package 2.5.1 for Swift in IOS.

Pre-bundled maps would be a central piece in a possible app. I looked at the instructions available at http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/creating-an-app-with-a-pre-bundled-map/, but things appears to have changed since then.

The folder structure does not match the blog post. After downloading some maps through the simulator, I find the .skm files located  in (for example) CoreSimulator/Devices/33D8[...]A72/Library/SE/SE.skm

In the SKMaps.bundle, I can find find a PreinstalledMaps/v1 folder, which only contains a text file. No 2015xxxx folder, or no SKMaps.zip or anything.

Is there some documentation regarding how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the demo project structure changed from the time of the blog post (we're updating the blog post).

What you need to do for 2.5.1:

- inside the PreinstaleldMaps/v1 folder
- create a 20150413 folder with 2 subfolders
- /package - drop the .skm files here
- /meta - here you need to put the contents from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wntbbldjly8fnpb/AAB49Eo2oRC0Nqw3D9DqOWlga?dl=0) (these files are also available in the demo project - I'm providing a direct link for convenience)

It should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Works fine. Thanks! But you mentioned 3 subfolders, and only listed two?

Comment: Only 2 subfolders - I've edited the answer to correctly reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I have installed `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK`, '~> 3.0.3' from the pod file and put the pre-installed map of the `KYCITY`.

But it is not showing the offline map?

All folder and data are same.[Offline Map Pre-installed folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ko2.png)